# How can I substitute the values into an sql expression in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

What's the de-facto way to do this sorts of things in NodeJs:

```
con.query("""
          update something 
          set aaa = ???,
          bbb = ???,
          where ccc = ??? and ddd = ???
        """, function (err, result) {
```

I mean, how can I substitute the values into the sql request **properly** and easily?

Comment: A better approach would be to use place holder  name `aaa = :aaa` and then pass the values as object. Looks like you are using the node mysql module check here https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#custom-format

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, will I have to implement "connection.config.queryFormat"? or is `aaa = :aaa` available by default?

Comment: Well you dont need to have `queryFormat` you can do something as `con.query('update something set aaa = ? ,  bbb = ?  where ccc = ? and ddd = ?',[array with values in sequence], function (err,result) { //your code here}) ;`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply for your code as below:

```
var sql = phpjs.strtr("SELECT * FROM :table WHERE id = :id",
    {
        ":table"        : my_table,
        ":id"           : my_id
    }
);
myClient.query(sql, callback);
```

Example:

```
var sql = phpjs.strtr("UPDATE something SET aaa = :a, bbb = :b WHERE ccc = :c AND ddd = :d",
    {
        ":a"        : my_a,
        ":b"        : my_b,
        ":c"        : my_c,
        ":d"        : my_d
    }
);
con.query(sql, function (err, result){
    //stmt
});
```